# Можно ли с помощью 3G-модема через СМС дать команду к ОС?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sms, ос, модемы

Можно ли с помощью 3G-модема(с симкой) через СМС дать команду к ОС?

Есть терминал который выходить в интернет через 3G-модем, иногда связь пропадает и приходится идти в то место где стоит терминал и вручную перезагружать ОС чтобы связь появилась. **Теперь вопрос:** можно ли как-то настроить модем(с симкой) и ОС чтобы при отсутствия связи, можно было смской отправить команду чтобы терминал перезагрузился? **Спасибо заранее за отклики!**

Comment: *теоретически это возможно*: для этого надо написать свое по, которое будет читать входящие смс и выполнять необходимые действия. статья на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/133085/) в которой есть необходимым минимум для *старта*

Comment: аппаратное решение рассматривали?

Comment: терминалов очень много, было бы супер если не будет финансовых затрат.

Comment: А просто написать скрипт для проверки интернета и автоматическую перезагрузку при его отсутствии не вариант?

Comment: Я делал подобное на одноплатменном комьютере. Модем подключал по UART (COM-порт). Есть либы на NodeJS для приема и отправки СМС (немного сыроваты). В принципе, с COM-портом возможно работать через minicom как по телнету. Пишешь 'AT+своя команда', получаешь результат. Вот что сделал бы я: написал скрипт на NodeJS и запустил бы его от рута.   [моя заметка по NodeJS для себя](https://pi.pushorigin.ru/details/gsm-neoway-m590)

Comment: развивая идею @andreymal если время последнего сеанса связи больше определенного значения, то в ребут

Comment: решения давно существуют и называются software watchdog